# what should be the values of tx fields if a row is entered from cqlsh instead from using DistributedTransaction

Tags: scalardb

In `ScalarDB`, what should be the values of tx fields if a row is entered from `cqlsh` instead from using `DistributedTransaction`?

My table's schema is

```
CREATE TABLE codingjedi.supported_tags (
    course text,
    subject text,
    topic text,
    before_tx_committed_at bigint,
    before_tx_id text,
    before_tx_prepared_at bigint,
    before_tx_state int,
    before_tx_version int,
    tx_committed_at bigint,
    tx_id text,
    tx_prepared_at bigint,
    tx_state int,
    tx_version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (course, subject, topic)
)
```

I populated some entries in the table from `cqlsh` directly `INSERT INTO supported_tags (course, subject, topic) VALUES ('coding','Perl','empty' ) IF NOT EXISTS;`

But this leaves `tx_committed_at tx_id, tx_prepared_at, tx_state, tx_version` `null`. I think this is causing issue when I do a `get`. I get an exception `invalid id specified.. Cause: null`.

Can I add rows in table from `cqlsh`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended. There is no guarantee of Scalar DB transaction. It is better to populate records via Scalar DB transaction.

I have never tried that. I guess that you can set `3` (which means `committed`) to `tx_state`, an integer value to `tx_version`, a bigint number to `tx_*_at`, and a string to `tx_id`.

Comment: These entries are system configuration and would not change (except for doing a `Get` on them.

Comment: Why not use (non-transactional) storage APIs in Scalar DB for them? I guess that they don't require transactional operations.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that there are such APIs! Could you please point me to the relevant section. I can't find them.

Comment: We can use `DistributedStorage` for that. It doesn't require these metadata like `tx_*` on a table.
Getting started document: https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/docs/getting-started-with-scalardb.md#store--retrieve-data-with-storage-service
JavaDoc: https://scalar-labs.github.io/scalardb/javadoc/com/scalar/db/api/DistributedStorage.html